# How to get a fast lambda function from an sympy expression in 3 dimensions?

Tags: python, numpy, sympy

I am using sympy to generate different expressions for cfd-simulations.
Mostly these expressions are of the kind exp = f(x,y,z) for example 
f(x,y,z) = sin(x)*cos(y)*sin(z). To get values  on a  grid I use simpy.lambdify. 
For example:

```
import numpy as np
import sympy as sp
from sympy.abc import x,y,z

xg, yg, zg = np.mgrid[0:1:50*1j, 0:1:50*1j, 0:1:50*1j]
f  = sp.sin(x)*sp.cos(y)*sp.sin(z)

lambda_f = sp.lambdify([x,y,z], f, "numpy")
fn = lambda_f(xg, yg, zg)

print fn
```

This seems to work pretty good but unfortunately my expressions are getting more and more complex and the grid computation takes a lot of time. 
My Idea was that it is maybe possible to use the uFuncify method
(see http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/numeric-computation.html )
to speed the computations up, im not sure if this is the right way ? 
And im also not sure how to get ufunctify to work for 3d grids ? 
Thanks for any Suggestions

Comment: The documentation `ufuncify` explicitly states: `The returned function can only act on one array at a time, as only the first argument accept arrays as input.` You'd still be forced to wrap your call to `ufuncify`'s returned argument in a double for loop. That *could* speed up some things, but it depends entirely on your equations.

Comment: Yes you are right, I hoped that there would be maybe some trick to do this. Anyway i guess a double for loop will probably also be slow but I'll give it a try. Is there maybe some alternative to ufuncify?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In previous releases (0.7.5 and prior), `ufuncify` only worked on single dimension arrays for the first argument (not very exciting). As of 0.7.6 (not released yet, but should be in a week!) `ufuncify` creates *actual* instances of `numpy.ufunc` by default (wraps C code in numpy api). Your code above only needs a small change to make it work.

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: from sympy import sin, cos, lambdify

In [3]: from sympy.abc import x,y,z

In [4]: from sympy.utilities.autowrap import ufuncify

In [5]: from sympy.printing.theanocode import theano_function

In [6]: xg, yg, zg = np.mgrid[0:1:50*1j, 0:1:50*1j, 0:1:50*1j]

In [7]: f  = sym.sin(x)*sym.cos(y)*sym.sin(z)

In [8]: ufunc_f = ufuncify([x,y,z], f)

In [9]: theano_f = theano_function([x, y, z], f, dims={x: 3, y: 3, z: 3})

In [10]: lambda_f = lambdify([x, y, z], f)

In [11]: type(ufunc_f)
Out[11]: numpy.ufunc

In [12]: type(theano_f)
Out[12]: theano.compile.function_module.Function

In [13]: type(lambda_f)
Out[13]: function

In [14]: %timeit ufunc_f(xg, yg, zg)
10 loops, best of 3: 21 ms per loop

In [15]: %timeit theano_f(xg, yg, zg)
10 loops, best of 3: 20.7 ms per loop

In [16]: %timeit lambda_f(xg, yg, zg)
10 loops, best of 3: 22.3 ms per loop
```

`ufuncify` and `theano_function` are comparable, and slightly faster than `lambdify` for this simple expression. The difference is greater using the more complicated expression given below:

```
In [17]: f = sin(x)*cos(y)*sin(z) + sin(4*(x - y**2*sin(z)))

In [18]: ufunc_f = ufuncify([x,y,z], f)

In [19]: theano_f = theano_function([x, y, z], f, dims={x: 3, y: 3, z: 3})

In [20]: lambda_f = lambdify([x, y, z], f)

In [21]: %timeit ufunc_f(xg, yg, zg)
10 loops, best of 3: 29.2 ms per loop

In [22]: %timeit theano_f(xg, yg, zg)
10 loops, best of 3: 29.2 ms per loop

In [23]: %timeit lambda_f(xg, yg, zg)
10 loops, best of 3: 42.1 ms per loop
```

This is *much* faster than using the python version, as no intermediate arrays are created, the loop is traversed and the calculation ran in C. Theano produces equivalent speeds, as they also compile to native code. For the large expressions that I see when doing [multibody dynamics](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/physics/mechanics/index.html), `ufuncify` (and the related `autowrap`) perform **significantly** faster than `lambdify`. I don't have much experience with theano, so I can't say how well their approach scales either, but I'd assume it would be similar.

As I said above, this is only available in sympy 0.7.6 and up. Should be released soon, but until then you can grab the source from [github](https://github.com/sympy/sympy). Docs on `ufuncify` new behavior can be found [here](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/utilities/autowrap.html#sympy.utilities.autowrap.ufuncify)

Comment: If you're interested, I gave a talk about the code generation stuff in sympy a while ago. Slides are [here](https://speakerdeck.com/jcrist/generating-fast-and-correct-code-with-sympy), with an example ipython notebook [here](https://github.com/jcrist/codegen_talk). Gives a pretty good overview of all the exciting functionality available in sympy 0.7.6.

Comment: This sounds really awesome, Thank You! I guess I will get the current dev-branch from github and check it out. Also thank you for the slides, I will have a look at them. Cheers!

Comment: @jammycrisp, could you perhaps add a speed benchmark comparing the `ufuncify` version to the `theano_function`?

Comment: @OliverW.: Done, see above.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you could work with sympy's `theano_function`. According to [the link to the documentation you provided](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/numeric-computation.html), it has similar speed as `ufuncify` and it can be used with an `mgrid`:

```
import numpy as np
import sympy as sp
from sympy.printing.theanocode import theano_function

x,y,z  = sp.symbols('x y z')
xg, yg, zg = np.mgrid[0:1:50*1j, 0:1:50*1j, 0:1:50*1j]
f  = sp.sin(x)*sp.cos(y)*sp.sin(z)

ft = theano_function([x,y,z], [f], dims={x: 3, y: 3, z: 3})
ft(xg,yg,zg)  # result is similar to your fn
```

For this particular function `f`, however, the execution speed on my system of the lambdified version and the theano-ized version is similar:

```
In [24]: %timeit fn = lambda_f(xg, yg, zg)
10 loops, best of 3: 53.2 ms per loop

In [25]: %timeit fn = ft(xg,yg,zg)
10 loops, best of 3: 52.7 ms per loop
```

Making the function slightly more difficult,

```
In [27]: f = sp.sin(x)*sp.cos(y)*sp.sin(z) + sp.sin(4*(x-y**2*sp.sin(z)))

In [30]: %timeit fl(xg,yg,zg)  # lambdified version
10 loops, best of 3: 89.4 ms per loop

In [31]: %timeit ft(xg,yg,zg)  # Theano version
10 loops, best of 3: 67.6 ms per loop
```

makes the timing differences slightly bigger for me (and in favor of theano), but perhaps on your functions you'd experience much bigger timing differences?

Comment: Thank you. Could be promising. ..  I'm not quiet sure if Theano supports double precision? I will try it out for a larger expression to see what the time difference is.

Comment: Theano supports double precision. The single precision limitation is only if you want to compile to the GPU.