# Theano gives TypeError: 'Add' object is not iterable

Tags: python, sympy, theano

I am using anaconda on linux, I have installed related packages.
I am trying to learn theano, for simplicity I want to run the following codes

```
    from sympy.printing.theanocode import theano_function
    import sympy as sp
    import numpy as np

    x, y, z = sp.symbols('x y z')
    f = sp.sin(x)*sp.cos(y)*sp.sin(z) + sp.sin(4*(x - y**2*sp.sin(z)))
    xg, yg, zg = np.mgrid[0:1:50*1j, 0:1:50*1j, 0:1:50*1j]

    theano_f = theano_function([x, y, z], f, dims={x: 3, y: 3, z: 3})

    ######################### 
    In [1]: %timeit theano_f(xg, yg, zg)
```

following the question in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26867172/how-to-get-a-fast-lambda-function-from-an-sympy-expression-in-3-dimensions). However, I get the following error:

```
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder_kernels/customize/spydercustomize.py", line 786, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder_kernels/customize/spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "/home/user/desktop/scripts/Anaconda3pros/pros/den.py", line 9, in <module>
    theano_f = theano_function([x, y, z], f, dims={x: 3, y: 3, z: 3})

  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sympy/printing/theanocode.py", line 235, in theano_function
    toutputs = list(map(code, outputs))

TypeError: 'Add' object is not iterable
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried enclosing `f` into a list in the `theano_function` and it ran without errors. Let me know if it gives the output you want.

```
from sympy.printing.theanocode import theano_function
import sympy as sp
import numpy as np

x, y, z = sp.symbols('x y z')
f = sp.sin(x)*sp.cos(y)*sp.sin(z) + sp.sin(4*(x - y**2*sp.sin(z)))
xg, yg, zg = np.mgrid[0:1:50*1j, 0:1:50*1j, 0:1:50*1j]

theano_f = theano_function([x, y, z], [f], dims={x: 3, y: 3, z: 3})
```